# Javascript: Get Selected Text From Textarea in IE8

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to read in the value of selected text within a text area.  Here is my code:

```
function readSelected(id)
{ 
    textarea = document.getElementById(id);
    if (document.selection)
    { //Code for IE
        textarea.focus();
        sel = document.selection.createRange();
        alert(sel.text);
    }
    else 
    {  // Code for Mozilla Firefox
        var len = textarea.value.length;
        var start = textarea.selectionStart;
        var end = textarea.selectionEnd;

        var scrollTop = textarea.scrollTop;
        var scrollLeft = textarea.scrollLeft;

        sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end);

        alert(sel);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="txt1" rows="10"></textarea> 
<a onclick="readSelected('txt1');">Get Selected</a>
```

When you click the button, a popup should occur telling you what the selected text is.

The code works in Firefox, but I can't get it to work in IE8.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that clicking on the `<a>` element destroys the selection. You could use an unselectable button instead:

```
<input type="button" value="get" onclick="readSelected('txt1');" unselectable="on">
```

There are other minor issues with your code

1. You should declare all your variables, otherwise they end up leaking into the global scope. `sel` and `textarea` are the offenders here.
2. `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` are redundant.
3. You should test for the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties first, since they're the standard (HTML 5 specifies them and IE 9 will support them).

Here's my rewritten version:

```
function readSelected(id) {
    var sel = "", el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        sel = el.value.slice(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        el.focus();
        sel = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    alert(sel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The code corrections are appreciated! Is there any reason to not use onmousedown as the other answerer suggested, assuming I make the neccesary JS corrections as you have suggested?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try with `onmousedown` instead of `onclick` ?

Comment: It works with `onmousedown`.  Is there any reason to use onclick vs onmousedown; other than that it works?  I'm not opposed to changing the `<a>` to `<input>`, as Tim suggested.

Comment: `onmousedown` if fired before the "deselection" of the text that occurs when the mouse is released.